# How many kills did Neil Armstrong have?

Tags: aviation-history

I realize this is slightly off topic, but there's no other SE site that it would at all fit into.

Anyway, I was just thinking about Neil Armstrong, and I wondered how many confirmed, and/or possible, kills he had in combat.

I tried to look it up, but couldn't find anything with Google.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the amount of kills an astronaut has.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but it seems like it would be on-topic at History SE. Questions about historical events and famous people are explicitly on-topic there.

Answer (score 7):

None, his combat unit was ground attack, not air to air, so it is unlikely he ever was involved in air to air combat.